# Problem with displaying pictures in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

i'm working on Laravel 7 , i want to display the images added by the administrator, but they don't show up.

This is the index.blade.php :

```
  @foreach ($posts as $post)
          <div class="col-3">
      <div class="product__item">
  <div class="product__item__pic set-bg" data-setbg="{{asset('product/September2020/'.$post->Photo)}}">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

This is the adress of the pictures : C:\wamp64\www\Projectclient\storage\app\public\product\September2020

Thanks fo help

Comment: Did you set APP_URL in .env file?

Comment: Can you show us what does `{{asset('product/September2020/'.$post->Photo)}}` returns? You can see that `src=""` in source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a symbolic link :

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Then a symbolic will create on your `public` folder with `storage/app/public`.  Then you can access it as :

```
{{ asset('storage/product/September2020/'.$post->Photo) }}
```