# Laravel images in storage link are broken

Tags: laravel, storage

In laravel i created storage using php artisan i cannot access my images on blade uploading works fine but i cannot even see them file they are broken. Even in using `http://localhost:8000/storage/ProductId-1601294060.jpg` laravel response is Not Found but images are there in the folder
Steps i have tried

```
<td><strong><img  src="/storage/product_image/ProductId-1601296148.jpg" height="150px" width="150px"/></strong></td>
```

step 2

```
<td> <img src="{{ URL::asset('/storage/product_image/ProductId-1601296148.jpg') }}" ></a></td>
```

step 3

```
<td><img src="{{asset('/storage/product_image/ProductId-1601296148.jpg')}}" class="img-size-50 mr-3 img-circle"></td>
```

also in file config file system i have added

```
'default' => 'public'
```

thanks

Comment: You mean: `http://localhost:8000/storage/product_image/ProductId-1601294060.jpg` ?

Comment: Show us how you upload the files, I suspect that you're uploading it to a private disk.

Comment: I answerd the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64099558/problem-with-displaying-pictures-in-laravel-7/64099759#64099759

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Laravel storage filesystem is so unique. When you doing any upload it will upload in the storage/app/public directory. To make it accessible in public directory, things need to do is create symlink by run command:*

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Or

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url("/product_image/ProductId-1601296148.jpg") }}" alt="" />
```

Comment: Thanks all i also have create storage link the problem was storage link was not storing images in public i.e product_image is not in public i don't now why when i move it there it works Thanks all . i have up voted all comments and answers really appreciate

Answer (score 1):

please try to create symlink in public folder and after that you will be able to access images
You can read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are using `asset(/storage..)` instead of `asset('storage...)`

Comment: Ok, I tried that out. And i think both should versions should work. I don't see your mistake in case you have used php artisan storage:link.